# Output is string and I want to get the data from an array

Tags: javascript

So I got indexes from one array and its returns me multiple indexes. And I want these indexes to get data from another array.

```
  let withAccent = array.map(x => x.TERM);
  let withoutAccent = terms
    .map(x => x.TERM)
    .join(",")
    .normalize("NFD")
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    .split(",");
  let withoutAccentPosition = withoutAccent
    .map((withoutAccent, idx) =>
      withoutAccent.includes(input) ? "withAccent[" + idx + "]" : null
    )
    .filter(e => e !== null)
    .join(", ");
  console.log(withoutAccentPosition);
  console.log(withAccent[0], withAccent[1], withAccent[22]);
```

withAccent;

> [ "ahoj", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "můžete",
>   "nebo", "pak", "postupně", … ]

withoutAccent:

> [ "ahoj", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "muzete",
>   "nebo", "pak", "postupne", … ]
>   Input is what user types

And now i got indexes from withoutAccent and i want to get data depends on the indexes from with Accent

So the first log returns string of withAccent[] positions and the second run properly, but i want the data from withoutAccentPosition.

Comment: The expression that sets `withoutAccentPosition` is based on the `withoutAccent` array. However, the code in the `.map()` callback uses the string `"withAccent["` instead of `"withoutAccent["` when it builds the return values.

Comment: @Pointy So what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know; it's really not very clear what the problem is. What you say you want appears to be what your code already does.

Comment: @Pointy withoutAccentPosition gives me number of indexes e.g 1,2,3,4 And i want to get values from withAccent on positions 1,2,3,4

Comment: You didn't post the original arrays (or any description of what they contain), and it's also a mystery what `input` is. Also note that inside the `.map()` callback for the `withoutAccentPosition` array, the variable `withoutAccent` will refer to each individual element of the `withoutAccent` array, not the array itself.

Comment: Well your question says "but I want the data from withoutAccentPosition".

Comment: @Pointy I edited the main topic.

Comment: Well I *think* all you need to do is stop building those strings, and just return the indexes as numbers. Then you can use `withAccent[withoutAccentPosition[0]]`, `withAccent[withoutAccent[1]]`, etc. I'm not sure about that because it is still not clear to me what it is you want to do.

Comment: In the withAccent array is words with accent and in the withoutAccent are without accent and I want to get when user types muzete it returns můžete

Comment: @Pointy long story short I'm getting string withAccent[0], withAccent[1], withAccent[2] And i want to be in array.

Comment: Hi @mckvak withAccent is already an array.. if you will do withAccent[0] than ofcourse it will return data at index 0 which is string

Comment: @Rishab hello i understand, but user type muzete and it get index of muzete from withoutaccent and what  I want  is to get this index which i already have e.g 5 and it would take můžete from withaccent and paste it to array.

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not use the join()** if you need to get the array. The **join()** method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array.

Here is solution

```js
var input = 'muzete' ;

var withAccent =[ "ahoj", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "můžete", "nebo", "pak", "postupně"];
var withoutAccent =  [ "ahoj", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "muzete", "nebo", "pak", "postupne" ];

let withoutAccentPosition = withoutAccent
    .map((withoutAccent, idx) =>
        withoutAccent.includes(input) ? "withAccent[" + idx + "]" : null
    ).filter(e => e !== null);
console.log(withoutAccentPosition);
console.log(withAccent[0], withAccent[1], withAccent[22]);
```

If you need the direct values then use directly withAccent[idx] instead of making it a string type

```js
var input = 'muzete' ;

var withAccent =[ "ahoj", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "můžete", "nebo", "pak", "postupně"];
var withoutAccent =  [ "ahoj", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "muzete", "nebo", "pak", "postupne" ];

let withoutAccentPosition = withoutAccent
    .map((withoutAccent, idx) =>
        withoutAccent.includes(input) ? withAccent[idx] : null
    ).filter(e => e !== null);
console.log(withoutAccentPosition);
console.log(withAccent[0], withAccent[1], withAccent[22]);
```

Comment: thanks but it gaves me "withAccent[6]" not můžete, and its the problem which I want to solve. i know I probably didnt explait it well.

Comment: Check both solutions , second solution is exact what you need můžete